# raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other)) ValueError: Shapes (3, 3, 3, 32) and (3, 3, 3, 16) are incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, opencv, yolo

I am trying to use yolov3 and tensorflow to detect objects and i was following the youtube tutorial to understand what im doing since i dont have experience in coding.
after i ran the code i got this error that i couldn't fine a solution for.
i tired to lower my numpy version to 1.16.4 but it wont let me so i lowered it to 1.16.5 but still the same error apereas

```
from absl import flags
import sys
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
FLAGS(sys.argv)

import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf
from yolov3_tf2.models import YoloV3
from yolov3_tf2.dataset import transform_images
from yolov3_tf2.utils import convert_boxes

from deep_sort import preprocessing
from deep_sort import nn_matching
from deep_sort.detection import Detection
from deep_sort.tracker import Tracker
from tools import generate_detections as gdet

class_names = [c.strip() for c in open('./data/labels/coco.names').readline()]
yolo = YoloV3(classes=len(class_names))
yolo.load_weights('./weights/yolov3-tiny.tf')

max_cosine_distance = 0.5
nn_budget = None
nms_max_overlap = 0.8

model_filename = 'model_data/mars-small128.pb'
encoder = gdet.create_box_encoder(model_filename, batch_size=1)
metric = nn_matching.NearestNeighborDistanceMetric('cosine', max_cosine_distance, nn_budget)
tracker = Tracker(metric)

vid = cv2.VideoCapture('./data/video/testvideo')

codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
vid_fps = int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
vid_width, vid_height = int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),                         
int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('./data/video/results.avi', codec, vid_fps, (vid_width, vid_height))

while True:
    _, img = vid.read()
    if img is None:
        print('Completed')
        break

img_in = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img_in = tf.expand_dims(img_in, 0)
img_in = transform_images(img_in, 416)

t1 = time.time()

boxes, scores, classes, nums = yolo.predict(img_in)

classes = classes[0]
names = []
for i in range(len(classes)):
    names.append(class_names[int(classes[i])])
names = np.array(names)
converted_boxes = convert_boxes(img, boxes[0])
features = encoder(img, converted_boxes)

detections = [Detection(bbox, score, class_name, feature) for bbox, score, class_name, feature in
              zip(converted_boxes, scores[0], names, features)]

boxes = np.array([d.tlwh for d in detections])
scores = np.array([d.confidence for d in detections])
classes = np.array([d.class_name for d in detections])
indices = preprocessing.non_max_suppression(boxes, classes, nms_max_overlap, scores)
detections = [detections[i] for i in indices]

tracker.predict()
tracker.update(detections)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('tab20b')
colors = [cmap(i)[:3] for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 20)]

for track in tracker.tracks:
    if not track.is_confirmed() or track.time_since_update > 1:
        continue
    bbox = track.to_tlbr()
    class_name = track.get_class()
    color = colors[int(track.track_id) % len(colors)]
    color = [i * 255 for i in color]

    cv2.rectangle(img, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])), color, 2)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]- 30)), (int(bbox[0]) + (len(class_name)
    + len(str(track.track_id))) * 17, int(bbox[1])), color, -1)
    cv2.putText(img, class_name+"-"+str(track.track_id), (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1] - 10)),
    0, 0.75, (255, 255, 255), 2)

fps = 1. / (time.time() - t1)
cv2.putText(img, "FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps), (0, 30), 0, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.resizeWindow('output', 1024, 768)
cv2.imshow('output', img)
out.write(img)

if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
    break
    vid.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is the error

Two checkpoint references resolved to different objects

```
(<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x0000011AFDB85A88> and <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.UpSampling2D object at 0x0000011AFDAF6048>).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Zahrani/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    yolo.load_weights('./weights/yolov3-tiny.tf')
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 181, in load_weights
    return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 1149, in load_weights
    status = self._trackable_saver.restore(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\util.py", line 1270, in restore
    checkpoint=checkpoint, proto_id=0).restore(self._graph_view.root)
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 209, in restore
    restore_ops = trackable._restore_from_checkpoint_position(self)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 908, in _restore_from_checkpoint_position
    tensor_saveables, python_saveables))
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\util.py", line 289, in restore_saveables
    validated_saveables).restore(self.save_path_tensor)
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saving\functional_saver.py", line 255, in restore
    restore_ops.update(saver.restore(file_prefix))
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saving\functional_saver.py", line 102, in restore
    restored_tensors, restored_shapes=None)
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\saving\saveable_object_util.py", line 115, in restore
    self.handle_op, self._var_shape, restored_tensor)
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 291, in shape_safe_assign_variable_handle
    shape.assert_is_compatible_with(value_tensor.shape)
  File "C:\Users\Zahrani\miniconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 1115, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (3, 3, 3, 32) and (3, 3, 3, 16) are incompatible
```

Comment: The error tells you that some operation was attempted on tensors of different shapes. Maybe you loaded weights from a different model with something of size 32, while in your current instantiation of `YoloV3` that thing has size 16, or vice versa. How did you obtain `'./weights/yolov3-tiny.tf'` and what's `len(class_names)`?

Comment: i downloaded the weights from [https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov3_deepsort#command-line-args-reference] yolov3-tiny.tf is the weights( pre trained file) after converting from the yolov3-tiny weights to a tensorflow file. and len(class_names) is the length of the names of the objects that i might detect.